# Wrapping browser.WaitUntil () Using Await and Async

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I have to use async and await everywhere in my code. How can I get the code below to work with async/await? The code below results in a timeout.

```
await browser.waitUntil(
     async () => (await (await selector).getAttribute("value")) === pricePerUnit
```

The origin code worked just fine.

```
selector.setValue(selection)
    browser.waitUntil(() => {
      return selector.getAttribute('value') === selection
    })
```

Comment: If browser waitUntil is not a promise, use a promise constructor,.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
await browser.waitUntil(
    async () => (await $('#someText').getText()) === 'I am now different',
    {
        timeout: 5000,
        timeoutMsg: 'expected text to be different after 5s'
    }
);
```